# Citizen thermal printer ZPL inconsistent text alignment

Tags: zpl, thermal-printer

I am having issues with consistency of text alignment printing ZPL between official Zebra hardware and a Citizen CL-S521 (and presumably other Citizen models).

I have a label with 270 degree rotation on some fields that need to be left-aligned, yet the printer is outputting them right aligned. Equally I have some text blocks that are supposed to be right aligned, but are printing left aligned, with an incorrect field origin.

Examples:

^FWB,0

^FO40,570,0^A0,23,24^TBB,450,25FH\^FDThis should be left aligned^FS

And:

^FT790,504,1^A0N,31,31^TBN,90,31^FH\^FDThis should be right aligned^FS

Using an online ZPL viewer and other ZPL-compatible printers, this outputs correctly, just not on the Citizen models.

If anyone else has had a similar issue and resolved it I would be grateful to understand how.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this problem, I solved it using the ^FB Field Block command instead of ^TB Text Block, despite the Zebra ZPLII guide advising against this.

Citizen support confirmed their printers do not support the ^TB command at the moment.